# Sherlock + DeviceDefault

Tags: android, themes, actionbarsherlock

Could one use Action Bar Sherlock together with the DeviceDefault theme (on >4.2), and with the regular Theme (as it used to be on <3.0)?

The pointe is of course that I suspect Sherlock forces you to use its own themes (some of which are based on Holo).

Comment: Why would someone not want to use the holo theme...

Comment: On Gingerbread one would want to use the native (not Holo) theme. So that would be the yellowish-grey with round corners on a Nexus One. But on an Evo 4G (because of HTC's mods) it would be green on white with round corners. For the reason of UI consistency for the end-user.

Answer (score 1):

In `values/themes.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" extends="Theme.Sherlock">
</style>
```

In `values-v14/themes.xml`:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" extends="android:Theme.DeviceDefault">
</style>
```

And then use `Theme.MyApp` in your manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Sherlock.Holo theme just applies the holo theme to the ActionBar. As you can see from the Sherlock.Theme for APIs below 11:

```
<style name="Theme.Sherlock" parent="Sherlock.__Theme">
        <!-- Action bar styles (from Theme.Holo) -->
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton</item>
        <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow</item>
        <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/abs__cab_background_top_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/abs__cab_background_bottom_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/abs__ic_cab_done_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabView</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar.TabText</item>
        <item name="actionModeStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionMode</item>
        <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.CloseMode</item>
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="actionBarSize">@dimen/abs__action_bar_default_height</item>
        <!-- Internal --><item name="actionModePopupWindowStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.PopupWindow.ActionMode</item>
        <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@null</item>

        <!-- Action bar styles (defaults from Theme) -->
        <item name="actionBarSplitStyle">?attr/actionBarStyle</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.ActionBar.Menu</item>
        <item name="actionMenuTextColor">?attr/textColorPrimary</item>
        <item name="actionBarDivider">?attr/dividerVertical</item>
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">?attr/selectableItemBackground</item>

        <item name="buttonStyleSmall">@style/Widget.Sherlock.Button.Small</item>

        <item name="selectableItemBackground">@drawable/abs__item_background_holo_dark</item>

        <item name="activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/abs__activated_background_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="actionModeShareDrawable">@drawable/abs__ic_menu_share_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="activityChooserViewStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ActivityChooserView</item>

        <item name="homeAsUpIndicator">@drawable/abs__ic_ab_back_holo_dark</item>

        <item name="dividerVertical">@drawable/abs__list_divider_holo_dark</item>

        <item name="spinnerDropDownItemStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.DropDownItem.Spinner</item>
        <item name="spinnerItemStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.TextView.SpinnerItem</item>

        <item name="textColorPrimary">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimaryDisableOnly">@color/abs__primary_text_disable_only_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/abs__primary_text_holo_light</item>

        <!-- Internal --><item name="dropdownListPreferredItemHeight">48dip</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown</item>

        <item name="textAppearanceSmall">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Small</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceLargePopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu.Large</item>
        <item name="textAppearanceSmallPopupMenu">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.PopupMenu.Small</item>

        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.PopupMenu</item>
        <!-- Internal --><item name="listPopupWindowStyle">@style/Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow</item>

        <item name="searchDropdownBackground">@drawable/abs__search_dropdown_dark</item>
        <item name="searchViewTextField">@drawable/abs__textfield_searchview_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="searchViewTextFieldRight">@drawable/abs__textfield_searchview_right_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="searchViewCloseIcon">@drawable/abs__ic_clear</item>
        <item name="searchViewSearchIcon">@drawable/abs__ic_search</item>
        <item name="searchViewGoIcon">@drawable/abs__ic_go</item>
        <item name="searchViewVoiceIcon">@drawable/abs__ic_voice_search</item>
        <item name="searchAutoCompleteTextView">@style/Widget.Sherlock.SearchAutoCompleteTextView</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownHintAppearance">@style/TextAppearance.Sherlock.Widget.DropDownHint</item>

        <item name="windowActionBar">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">false</item>
        <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

There is no TextViewStyle or any other styling specified other than for the ActionBar, so you don't need to modify the theme.

All other stylings are done by the parent theme Sherlock.__Theme as you can see. And this Theme is basically just the NoTitleBar theme on APIs below 11.

```
<style name="Sherlock.__Theme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

So this won't override any other styles.

Comment: So, it only changes the ActionBar styles? Another developer may use HoloEverywhere to change the whole theme to Holo. 

But does it only change the ActionBar styles, or also some styles of the widgets in there, such as checkboxes and radio buttons, and if they are used elsewhere in the Activity they also have that style? I'm referring to almost the end of http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2011/04/customizing-action-bar.html.

And finally, is that a yes or a no to my question?

Comment: ABS only changes the ActionBar style. Nothing else as you can tell by the Sherlock.Theme. So no widgets etc. these are all handled by the default theme for devices running API 11< (android:Theme.NoTitleBar); on API >11 this theme will be android:Theme.Holo

Comment: It's not an answer still. You pose it uses Holo for >3.0, but do not mention DeviceDefault.

Comment: I said: `these are all handled by the default theme for devices running API 11< (android:Theme.NoTitleBar)` --> The widgets are handled by the device default

Comment: Oh, but DeviceDefault is a theme on >=14. See http://android-developers.blogspot.be/2012/01/holo-everywhere.html.